# How do I specify Tuple for typechecking in Scala, if I take it in as a parameter

Tags: scala

There doesn't seem to be a class called Tuple in the package, only the Tuple_ for effective access. If I want to take a tuple into constructor as a parameter what do I do?

```
class DataElement( datatype: Datatype, values: () ) extends Element {
```

This doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All tuple classes implement `Product`, so you could use that.

Comment: But will I be able to pass variable number of arguments?

Comment: @vrode: No, if you want variable number of arguments, you have to use `values: ArgType*`. This is _not_ a tuple.

Comment: You will be able to pass a tuple of arbitrary length, but "variable number of arguements" is something else, as Alexey correctly pointed out.

Comment: A tuple of arbitrary length is exactly what I need. Thank you